# Javascipt add parent to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

am having issues displaying an array in react-native-sectioned-multi-select which accept array that have children i want to create array like this ,

```
StaffData: [ {
name: 'Users',
id: 0,
// these are the children or 'sub items'
children: [
  {
    name: 'Apple',
    id: 10,
  },
  {
    name: 'Strawberry',
    id: 17,
  },
  {
    name: 'kolo',
    id: 13,
  },
  {
    name: 'mo',
    id: 14,
  },
  {
    name: 'n',
    id: 15,
  },
  {
    name: 'n',
    id: 16,
  },
],
}]
```

**from this**
basically i want the below array to to have a parent that has 'id' and 'name' as above array

```
var secondarray = 
{"StaffData":
[{"id":1,"name":"Obi"},
{"id":2,"name":"Logistics"},
{"id":3,"name":"Security"},
{"id":4,"name":"Admin"},
{"id":5,"name":"Admin2"}]}
```

so if i cant do it, how can i display the second array on react-native-sectioned-multi-select

Comment: Can you share what code you have been working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but since `secondarray.StaffData` already seems to be the exact data you want in `StaffData.children`, just use an array/object literal in the format that you want:

```
let StaffData = [{
    name: 'Users',
    id: 0,
    children: secondarray.StaffData
}];
```